# Search and replace $ signs with sed

Tags: bash, unix, sed, replace

I would like to use sed to replace in files placeholders written like this $$placeholder$$ with the content of a variable.

Is it even possible ?

This is what I tried:

```
sed -i "" -e 's/\$\$placeholder\$\$/$o/g' test.txt
```

Half working, replace $$placeholder$$ by $o instead of the content of the $o variable

`sed -i "" -e "s/\$\$placeholder\$\$/$o/g" test.txt`

Not matching any of the $$placeholder$$ in my text

Thanks by advance.

Cyril

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
sed 's/\$\$placeholder\$\$/'"$o"'/g'
```

Comment: I found this used online, but I think it breaks when `$o` contains sed-specific characters like `/`, which in this case is the delimiter

Comment: sed allows different delimiters like `#` or `|` if there is a chance of using `/` in `$o`.

Comment: Whatever delimiter you use, there will always be a way to break `sed`. I think a *definitive* solution would be to encode the replacement

Comment: For that matter most of the shell scripts can be made to break by supplying weird values, all that matters is whether solution works with the requirements of the OP.

Comment: Sure, still you added double quotes around `$o` ;)

Comment: Double quotes ensure that the script is not broken if `$o` contains whitespace. So your this solution is more robust than others, but can still be easily broken. You did a first step, I think another should be done

Comment: Do you have to use sed? You could do it in something else, e.g. ruby. For example: ruby -e "puts STDIN.read.gsub! '\$\$placeholder\$\$', '$o'"

Comment: This solution is perfect for my needs. I also think double quotes around the $o make this reliable. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

double escape the dollar:

```
sed -i "s/\\$\\$placeholder\\$\\$/$o/g" test.txt
```

in case your variable contains your delimiter, you might do some string substitution on it first:

```
sed -i "s/\\$\\$placeholder\\$\\$/${o//\//\\/}/g" test.txt
```

Comment: note that your don't have to use / as delimiter, you can use any character (:,%)

Answer (score 0):

You can add simple quotes around `$o` :

```
sed -i "" -e 's/\$\$placeholder\$\$/'$o'/g' test.txt
```

Comment: This breaks `sed` if `$o` contains forward slashes or some other sed-specific character

Answer (score 0):

sed is a fine tool for simple replacements on a single line, but for anything else (including using a variable in the substitution) just use awk:

```
$ cat file
foo $$placeholder$$ bar

$ o="hello
world"

$ sed 's/\$\$placeholder\$\$/'"$o"'/g' file
sed: -e expression #1, char 27: unterminated `s' command

$ awk -v o="$o" '{gsub(/\$\$placeholder\$\$/,o)}1' file
foo hello
world bar
```

That way you don't need to worry about any characters sed considers "special" or mess around with jumping back and for the between sed and shell on your command line by carefully quoting sections of your script.